How to add a non-breaking space on a Galaxy Tab S9 Ultra with Samsung's official dedicated keyboard with no numpad?
I bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab S9 Ultra that I'm gonna be using for work while my PC is getting repaired and I got the dedicated keyboard from Samsung. The only problem is I can't add a non-breaking space without a numpad.
On my Windows PC, I'm used to doing ALT + 255. But now on Android without a numpad, I have to find a way that lets me add non-breaking spaces without having to copy-paste it from other sources. I need it to be as efficient as pressing ALT + 255 if possible.
By the way, I'm using Firefox on Android since that's where all my bookmarks are and it's in sync with my PC so I don't have the option of moving to Chrome or another browser. (unless it's really necessary).

I'm thinking of whether using the keyboard's custom dictionary might help, though I've never used it personally.
